# What's wrong with this code to Display ABPersonViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void) vDisplayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] ;
    picker.personViewDelegate = self;
    picker.displayedPerson = person;
    picker.displayedProperties=@[@(kABPersonPhoneProperty),@(kABPersonEmailProperty),@(kABPersonBirthdayProperty),@(kABPersonOrganizationProperty),@(kABPersonJobTitleProperty),@(kABPersonDepartmentProperty),@(kABPersonNoteProperty),@(kABPersonCreationDateProperty)];
    // Allow users to edit the person’s information
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.allowsActions=YES;
    //[picker setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"allowsDeletion"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

After [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];

I got

```
2013-10-08 09:29:37.499 Recent Contact[5804:a0b] *** Assertion failure in +[CNContact propertyForPropertyID:], /SourceCache/AddressBookUI_Sim/AddressBookUI-1553/Framework/Sources/CNUIContact/CNContact.m:855
```

I do not even know what class CNContact is or why it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are wrong property you are trying to use. Instead try this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface PersonViewController : UIViewController <ABPersonViewControllerDelegate> 
{
ABPersonViewController *personController;
}

- (void) displayContactInfo: (ABRecordRef)person;

@end
```

delegate's implementation (PersonViewController.m):

```
#import "PersonViewController.h"

@implementation PersonViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
}

 - (void) viewDidUnload
 {
[personController release];
 }

  - (void) displayContactInfo: (ABRecordRef)person
{
personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
[personController setDisplayedPerson:person];
[personController setPersonViewDelegate:self];
[personController setAllowsEditing:NO];
personController.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();   

personController.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], 
    nil];

[self setView:personController.view];
}

 - (BOOL) personViewController:(ABPersonViewController*)personView shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue
{
// This is where you pass the selected contact property elsewhere in your program
[[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Oh I should assing addressBook to ABAddressBookCreate()?